# Angularjs textarea not processing line breaks

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                        <label for="" class="control-label">Comments</label>                        
                        <div class="controls">
                            <textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="50" ng-model="$parent.comments" type="text"  ng-trim="false"></textarea>
                            {{comments}}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Inside my js controller is the following:

```
   $scope.updateComments = function()
     {


        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/create_comment/' + $scope.id+ '?comments=' + $scope.comments,
        })
        .success(function(data){
            $('#myModalComment').modal('hide');



        })


     }
```

Problem is that whenever I process line breaks from the textarea input, it doesn't process it.

For example if I want to type the following line:

```
 first line
 second line
```

My output would like like this:

first linesecond line

How do I cater to this problem?

UPDATE:

In case this maybe a back end issue where PHP esacpes the html characters, here is my function inside my php controller:

```
 public function createComments($id)
 {
    $comments = Input::get('comments');
    $log= Logger::find($id);
    $log->comments= $comments;
    $log->save();

 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I do understand you correctly, the issue is in these lines:

```
 <textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="50" 
    ng-model="$parent.comments" type="text"  ng-trim="false"></textarea>
 {{comments}}
```

that the `{{comments}}` is not showing line breaks.

But that's natural HTML behaviour. And there is also natural HTML solution **`<pre>`**:

```
 <textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="50" 
    ng-model="$parent.comments" type="text"  ng-trim="false"></textarea>
 <pre>{{comments}}</pre>
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp:

> The `<pre>` tag defines preformatted text.
>
> Text in a `<pre>` element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

Comment: hi, `{{comments}}` is actually just a preview of what's being input into the textarea. Using `<pre></pre>` will display me the correct output if I enter a new linebreak, but after performing the `updateComments()` and it inserts into my database, the linebreaks disappear.

Comment: I see that you are passing the comment as url param. Could not you send that as a JSON? or FORM like (key/value pairs) - simply inside of the POST request **BODY**. It seems to me, that url has not encoded the line breaks...

Comment: @user3278616,  Have you tried this: `$log->comments= nl2br($comments);`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.$watch('$parent.comments', function(newVal) {
    var newVal= newVal.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
    $scope.$parent.comments = newVal;
},true);
```

try something like this :)

Comment: when I input: 
first
second

I get an error:Syntax Error: Token 'second' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [first
second] starting at [second].